# How can I check a column in oracle which is blank and datatype is NUMBER

Tags: oracle

I have a table which name is HARDWARE_ISSUE . it has two column div_code and branch code . Datatype of div_code is NUMBER and branch_code is varchar2. I want to select branch_code when the value of div_code is `blank`. My query is below:

```
select  (case when div_code= null then  to_char(branch_code) else to_char(div_code) end) as brordiv  from HARDWARE_ISSUE
```

But It could not select branch_code when div_code is empty. I also run the query below:

```
   select * from HARDWARE_ISSUE where div_code= null
```

It also not produce any row. but there 15 rows which contain empty div_code. I am using oracle 11g. Please help me.

Comment: `... where div_code IS null`

Comment: [The documentation has a section on nulls](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm).

Comment: Do you need to filter rows or to extract all the rows? If you need a filter, you need a WHERE , otherwise you can simpify your code with NVL or COALESCE

Answer (score 0):

[Coalesce](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions033.htm#SQLRF00617):

```
select coalesce(to_char(div_code), branch_code) as brordiv
from hardware_issue
```

Comment: Hmmm. Per OP's statement `DIV_CODE` is NUMBER while `BRANCH_CODE` is VARCHAR2. `COALESCE` will throw an `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes` error. NVL, however, should work fine here because it will cast DIV_CODE to character.

Comment: You're right. I was misleaded by the fact that the OP applies to_char to both the fields, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a few possibilities:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TO_CHAR(DIV_CODE), BRANCH_CODE) AS BRORDIV
  FROM HARDWARE_ISSUE
```

will work around the ORA-00932 that I pointed on in my comment on @Aleksej's answer. Also

```
SELECT NVL(DIV_CODE, BRANCH_CODE) AS BRORDIV
  FROM HARDWARE_ISSUE
```

will auto-cast DIV_CODE to VARCHAR2 and thus hide the issue - but there's still a cast to VARCHAR2 involved which means you may not get the datatype you expect.

And always remember to use `SOME_COLUMN IS NULL` rather than `SOME_COLUMN = NULL`. The first will work as expected - the second will not.

Answer (score -1):

try it like this

```
select  (case when div_code= null then  to_char(branch_code) else 
to_char(div_code) end) as brordiv  from HARDWARE_ISSUE where div_code IS null
```

Comment: select  (case when div_code Is null then  to_char(branch_code) else to_char(div_code) end) as brordiv  from HARDWARE_ISSUE      is works.Thanks

Comment: you still have `div_code = null` ; besides, what should the `CASE` do, if you filter for rows where `div_code is null` ?

Comment: I want to pick branch_code when div_code is empty. The query -SELECT COALESCE(TO_CHAR(DIV_CODE), BRANCH_CODE) AS BRORDIV
  FROM HARDWARE_ISSUE  produce the actual result. Thanks.